# Best way to create huge xml file by duplicating the element(including children) with dom or sax using Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, sax, stax

I have a xml file(ABC.xml) and i need to duplicate only the

```
<Transaction>...</Transaction>
```

multiple times(more than 100000 times) keeping the Header and Trailer intact creating NEW.xml whose final size may go upto 1GB. Also i have to increment the Uniqueid for every transaction in sequence.

As i m new to xml, i have been searching to this the best possible way, and im confused.
Can anyone please help me with the best way to do it(using DOM or SAX) and some piece of code.
Also can you please give me some links about it.

```
ABC.xml
========
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Header><Datetime><date>20130209</date><Time>01:12</Time></Datetime></Header>
<Transaction>
    <Uniqueid>1230001</Uniqueid>
<Affiliate>
    <Name>abc</Name>
    <Address>
        <line1>aaaa</line1>
        <line2>bbbb</line2>
        <line3>cccc</line3>
    </Address>
    <Amount>123.00</Amount>
    <Currency>USD</Currency>
    <Purpose>
        <line1>aaaa</line1>
        <line2>bbbb</line2>
        <line3>cccc</line3>
    </Purpose>
</Affiliate>
</Transaction>
<Trailer><TotalTransactions>1</TotalTransactions><TotalAmount>123<TotalAmount>    </Trailer>


NEW.xml
=======
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Header><Datetime><date>20130209</date><Time>01:12</Time></Datetime></Header>
<Transaction>
<Uniqueid>1230001</Uniqueid>
<Affiliate>
    <Name>abc</Name>
    <Address>
        <line1>aaaa</line1>
        <line2>bbbb</line2>
        <line3>cccc</line3>
    </Address>
    <Amount>123.00</Amount>
    <Currency>USD</Currency>
    <Purpose>
        <line1>aaaa</line1>
        <line2>bbbb</line2>
        <line3>cccc</line3>
    </Purpose>
</Affiliate>
</Transaction>
<Transaction>
<Uniqueid>1230002</Uniqueid>
<Affiliate>
    <Name>abc</Name>
    <Address>
        <line1>aaaa</line1>
        <line2>bbbb</line2>
        <line3>cccc</line3>
    </Address>
    <Amount>123.00</Amount>
    <Currency>USD</Currency>
    <Purpose>
        <line1>aaaa</line1>
        <line2>bbbb</line2>
        <line3>cccc</line3>
    </Purpose>
</Affiliate>
</Transaction>
<Trailer><TotalTransactions>2</TotalTransactions><TotalAmount>246<TotalAmount></Trailer>
```

Comment: "Huge file" automatically suggests "SAX" over DOM :)  Who knows - a simple "sed" script or Java in a read/write loop (i.e. simple text I/O) might be preferable to either DOM or SAX.  IMHO...

Answer (score 0):

It would help if your source XML were well-formed - it needs an outer wrapper element.

There are a number of XQuery processors available in Java, for example Saxon. Just execute the query

```
<doc>{doc/Header, for $i in 1 to 100000 return doc/Transaction, doc/Footer}</doc>
```

on the supplied input document, assuming `<doc>` as the outer wrapper element.

Comment: Mike, this is the sample xml provided to me and was told it is a correct one and does not have an outer wrapper.

Comment: Don't believe what people tell you, check the specs. Technically your sample is not a well-formed document, though it is a well-formed external parsed entity. That basically means it's only usable as part of a larger XML document.